# Trigonometry of an hyperbolic Omega Triangle

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I was puzzeling with the trigonometry of an Omega Triangle ( a triangle / biangle  in hyperbolic geometry where one of the vertices is an Ideal point see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle#Ideal_vertices )

And using the Poincare disk model ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model )

Translated the Omega triangle to the following problem in Euclidean geometry:

(the angle $\angle AOB $ in one of the angles of the Omega triangle the other angle is $\angle CAO - 90 ^{\circ} $ )

Given:

- the unit circle (circle centered around $ (0 . 0)$ and radius 1 )
- a point $A = (a,0) $ with $ 0 < a < 1 $
- a point $ B$ on the arc of the unit circle with $0^\circ < \angle AOB < 90^\circ $
- A circle $c$ with centre $C$ such that $c$ is orthogonal to the unit circle and passes trough $A$ and $B$

Question:

- What is $ \angle CAO$ as function of  $ \angle AOB $ and $ a$ ?

Comment: What does it mean that a circle is "orthogonal" to another circle?

Comment: I found this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalCircles.html

Comment: I don't understand how the two circles can be orthogonal *and* $a<1$. Could you include a drawing please?

Comment: added some background to the question, hope to reopen it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cosine of angle $CAO=$

$$\frac{\left(a^2-1\right)\sin  \theta }{1+a^2-2a \cos  \theta }$$

where $\theta$ is angle $AOB$

Outline of a proof usin trig

Let $OB=1, OA=a, AB=b, BC=CA=c$

angles in degrees: $CAO=x, AOB=\theta, OBA=\beta,CAB=ABC=90-\beta$

Law of Sines: $\frac{\sin  \beta }{a}=\frac{\sin  \theta }{b}$

Calculating $\text{OC}^2$ in two different ways we get

$$a^2+c^2-2a c \cos  x=c^2+1$$

and therefore $2a c \cos  x=a^2-1$

On the other hand

$$\frac{a \sin  \theta }{b}=\sin  \beta =\cos  (90-\beta )=\frac{b}{2c}$$

$$2a c \sin  \theta =b^2$$

$$\cos  x = \frac{\left(a^2-1\right)\sin  \theta }{b^2}=\frac{\left(a^2-1\right)\sin  \theta }{1+a^2-2a \cos  \theta }$$

Some interesting special cases:
$$a=\cos  \theta , x=\theta +\pi /2$$
$$a=2 \cos  \theta , x = 3\theta -\pi /2$$
$$\theta =\pi /2, x=\arccos  \left(\frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}\right)$$

another special case

$$\cos  \theta  = \frac{2a}{a^2+1},x=\pi $$

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Here an answer put in equations (perhaps there may be another easier one). Do not solve the system nor calculate the angle between the straight lines $CA$ and $OA$ (I leave this as an exercise for the OP).

In order to know angle $\angle {CAO}$ one can find out the two points $B=(x_1,y_1)$ and $C=(x_2,y_2)$ so there are four unknowns, therefore one needs four (independent) equations.

**First equation**.- $B$ is in the unit circle: $$x_1^2+y_1^2=1\qquad (1)$$
**Second equation**.-$C$ is in the line segment bisector of $\overline{AB}$. The midpoint of $\overline{AB}$ being $M=(\frac {x_1+a}{2},\frac {y_1}{2})$ and the slope of $\overline{AB}$ being $\frac{y_1}{x_1-a}$ we have
$$\frac{2y_2-y_1}{2x_2-x_1}=\frac{-x_1+a}{y_1}\iff 2y_1y_2+2(x_1-a)x_2+ax_1=1\qquad (2)$$
**Third equation**.- $|\overline{CB}|=|\overline{CA}|$ (radius of the circle $c$).
$$(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2= (x_2-a)^2+y_2^2\iff 2(a-x_1)x_2-2y_1y_2+1=-2ax_2+a^2\qquad (3)$$
**Fourth equation**.-Line $CB$ is tangent to the unit circle.
$$\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}=\frac{-x_1}{y_1}\iff x_1x_2+y_1y_2=1\qquad (4)$$

Comment: the denominator of the first fraction in eq $(2)$ should read $2x_2-\left(x_1+a\right)$

Comment: @Lozenges: Thank you very much. I have too much distractions these times.